# About Baire spaces

Tags: general-topology

I'm having difficult to solve this:
Determine whether or not $\mathbb{R}_l$ is a Baire space.

I tried to aplly the following lemma: "X is a Baire space iff given any countable collection $\mathbb{U}_n$ of open sets in X, each of which is dense in X, their intersection $\bigcap{U}_n$ is also dense in X."

Where $\mathbb{R}_l$ is the topology of lower limit, generated by the intervals [a,b).

Could you help to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R}_l$ an unorthodox way to denote the $l$-dimensional real space? If so, there is a famous theorem that can help, "A complete metric space is a Baire space. Also, a locally compact space is a Baire space."

Comment: I'm not sure if $\mathbb{R}_l$ defined like above satisfies the conditions of the Baire theorem. 
Thank you @DanielFischer.

Comment: Ah, that's an entirely different matter. Would have been too easy. I don't know offhand whether that's a Baire space.

Comment: Thank anyway @DanielFischer
I'll keep trying here.

Comment: I'll try to see if I can solve it without too much work too, it's interesting. But now I'm going to bed.

Comment: See [this](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=homework_help_2003;task=show_msg;msg=0878.0001.0001).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose topologies $\sigma$ and $\tau$ on a set $X$ are such that every nonempty set from $\sigma$ contains a nonempty set from $\tau$, and the other way around. This is the case for the standard and lower-limit topology on the real line. You should be able to show that, for $Y \subset X$,

- the $\sigma$-interior of $Y$ is empty if and only if the $\tau$-interior of $Y$ is empty.
- $Y$ is $\sigma$-nowhere dense if and only if $Y$ is $\tau$-nowhere dense.

It follows that $\sigma$ is Baire if and only if $\tau$ is Baire.

Comment: @Charles: No problem! Here's something else which might be fun to think about. A standard application of Baire's theorem is to showing the nowhere differentiable functions are (uniformly) dense in the continuous functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. I think continuous functions $\mathbb{R}_\ell \to \mathbb{R}$ are the same thing as "left continuous" functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Maybe you can use your result to prove that the space of left continuous functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has to densely contain some similarly nonintuitive set of functions.

Comment: Ow nice @Mike! I will think about it!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more direct proof.

Let $U_n$ be open and dense in $\mathbb{R}_l$. Consider $\text{Int}(U_n)$ where the interior is taken with respect to $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\text{Int}(U_n)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. To show that $\text{Int}(U_n)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, let $V$ be any open set of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $V$ is also open in $\mathbb{R}_l$ so $V\cap U_n$ is non-empty and open in $\mathbb{R}_l$.This means $V\cap U_n$ contains a basis element of the form $[a,b)$ (where $a<b$), so it contains an interval $(a,b)$. In the topology of $\mathbb{R}$, $(a,b)$ is open so $(a,b)\subseteq \text{Int}(U_n)\cap V$. This proves that $\text{Int}(U_n)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a Baire space, $\bigcap \text{Int}(U_n)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $\bigcap U_n$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. To show that $\bigcap U_n$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}_l$, it suffices to show that any given basis element $[a,b)$ intersects $\bigcap U_n$. But $[a,b)$ contains $(a,b)$ which intersects $\bigcap U_n$ since the latter is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.